# derived symmetric powers of an ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be the polynomial algebra in $n$ variables over a field $F$ of characteristic $0$. Let $m$ be the ideal of the origin: $m=(x_1,...,x_n)$. 
We have a canonical map $Lsym^k(m)\to m^k$ from the derived symmetric power of $m$ to its $k$-th power, given by multiplication.

Here by the derived symmetric power I mean the (in general derived, here its exact) fixed points of the symmetric group $S_k$ in the $k$-fold derived tensor product of $m$ with itself.

I tried to compute this map by brute force using kozul complex in few small cases, and if i'm not mistaken (but I clearly might be!), it is a quasi-isomorphism in the case where $n=2$ or for $n=3$ and $k=2$.

An equivalent way to say that is that $Lsym^k(m)$ has no higher homologies.

Is it true in general? and if not, what are the conditions?